# Java Compiler preferring `int` type even if short and bytes are possible

Tags: java, compiler-optimization, jls

I tried below code, and I was amazed to see that my IDE indicated which method would be called... (of course by compiling).

```
public class Test20 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test20().m1(3);
    }


    void m1(long l){
        System.out.println("Long");
    }
    void m1(short s){
        System.out.println("Short");
    }
    void m1(byte b){
        System.out.println("By" + b);
    }
    void m1(int i){
        System.out.println("Int");
    }
    void m1(Integer ik){
        System.out.println("Integer");
    }
}
```

My point is if `3` could easily fit into `byte` size of 8-bit, then why Java Compiler takes it as `int` by default.

As `3` is constant and will never change as none of it's reference is present, it should have been stored into `byte` size for space optimization purpose. But, it is stored as `constant value 3 as int type` in compiled program.

Here is the output of `javap -c Test20.class`

```
Compiled from "Test20.java"
public class Test20 {
public Test20();
  Code:
    0: aload_0
    1: invokespecial #1                  // Method java/lang/Object."<init>":()V
    4: return

public static void main(java.lang.String[]);
  Code:
    0: new           #2                  // class Test20
    3: dup
    4: invokespecial #3                  // Method "<init>":()V
    7: iconst_3
    8: invokevirtual #4                  // Method m1:(I)V
    11: return

void m1(long);
  Code:
    0: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    3: ldc           #6                  // String Long
    5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    8: return

void m1(short);
  Code:
    0: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    3: ldc           #8                  // String Short
    5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    8: return

void m1(byte);
  Code:
    0: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    3: new           #9                  // class java/lang/StringBuilder
    6: dup
    7: invokespecial #10                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder."<init>":()V
    10: ldc           #11                 // String By
    12: invokevirtual #12                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    15: iload_1
    16: invokevirtual #13                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.append:(I)Ljava/lang/StringBuilder;
    19: invokevirtual #14                 // Method java/lang/StringBuilder.toString:()Ljava/lang/String;
    22: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    25: return

void m1(int);
  Code:
    0: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    3: ldc           #15                 // String Int
    5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    8: return

void m1(java.lang.Integer);
  Code:
    0: getstatic     #5                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
    3: ldc           #16                 // String Integer
    5: invokevirtual #7                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
    8: return
  }
```

I tried finding similar question on stackoverflow and other platforms, but could not find anything similar to this. Please suggest some reads, or explanation about this happening.

Comment: `3` is a literal of type `int` though - doesn't matter that it could fit into a smaller data type

Comment: A literal number such as `3` in your source code is of type `int` (those are just the rules of the Java language) so it's treated as an `int`.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10

Comment: Thank you all of you for comments and reference..!! @JBNizet that reference says "This chapter specifies the lexical structure of the Java programming language." So, after passing lexical tokens to compilers, can't it be optimized at compile time to save spaces.??

Comment: yes, it can be optimized... but maybe it is better to optimize memory access (e.g. 32 bit boundary [heap and so]) and I believe that there are not many operations in the virtual machine to deal with shorter values (short, byte, boolean)

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger http://java-performance.info/memory-introspection-using-sun-misc-unsafe-and-reflection/ this says all references in JVM occupy 4 bytes on heaps under 32G. And https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/113523 (last comment) says less sized data = faster comparison (or processing)??

Comment: ??? *the sky is blue!* How does that relate to the question? references !!!!!= literal; comparison speed !!!!!= memory access speed ( !!!!=  meaning VERY different [:-)  )

Comment: Ohk.. got it.. Could you please share any reference explaining `int` typed memory access are actually faster than that of `byte` ?? That would really help me to explore the blue skies. :P

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger https://cs.stackexchange.com/a/45797 : CPU is unaware of data type, it just reads what it is asked to do, so how reading `int` would be faster and `byte` would be slower. I'm still confused.!!

Comment: and now you come with CPU.and arithmetics.. again how does that relate to whatever was written here so far??? OK, so lets say you have bytes, shorts (2 bytes) and ints (4 bytes) on the heap. Now the virtual machine has to access the 3rd element of the heap (or stack), that is, it must go through each element and see what type it is to find the correct offset into the memory. If all values are just 4 bytes, it is a trivial calculation (just an example, very simplified)  Anyway the Java Language Specification simple states that `3` is an `int`, no matter why that is so... I can only speculate

Comment: and I can't share any reference since all I mentioned was from my experience (about 40 years?), that's why I wrote  "maybe it is...", "I believe that..." and not "it is". But I am sue there were a lot of architectures/frameworks/CPUs were access is always bound to each 4th byte.